# Как заменить текст на зеркале сайта без доступа к главному сайту?

Tags: php

Есть сайт, и есть его зеркало. Как можно заменить текст на зеркале сайта без доступа к основному сайту? В частности, нужно заменить номер телефона. Зеркало - региональный сайт основного сайта.